# utf-8 unicode error python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

```
new_text = text.decode('utf-8').replace('\u00a0', ' ').replace('\u00ad', ' ').replace('Â', ' ').replace('    ',' ').replace('   ', ' ').replace('  ', ' ').replace('\u20b9',' ').replace('\ufffd',' ').replace('\u037e',' ').replace('\u2022',' ').replace('\u200b',' ').replace('0xc3',' ')
```

This is the error produced by the code:

```
new_text = text.decode('utf-8').replace('\u00a0', ' ').replace('\u00ad', ' ').replace('Â', ' ').replace('    ',
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2017 15:22:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have tried decoding ascii from unicode.

Comment: What is `text`?

Comment: the text has been generated after converting a pdf document (using watson document converter ):  this a part of the text:[ no title

Bajaj Allianz General Insurance Company Ltd.

GE Plaza, Airport Road, Yerwada, Pune - 411006(India)

CERTIFICATE CUM POLICY SCHEDULE

Policy Servicing Off: Bajaj Finserv Building, 1st Floor, Behind Weikfield IT-Park, Viman Nagar, Pune-411014 Phone No :1800-209-0144 Product Private Car - Liability Only Policy Period Of Insurance From: 27-May-2017 Policy issued on 25-May-2017 - To: 26-May-2018 Midnight Cover Note No / Insured Name SANJAY SINGH ]

Comment: Do the replacements one at a time instead of all at once and figure out which one is causing the error.  If on Python 2, it is probably `.replace('Â', ' ')` and you need to use Unicode strings everywhere (`u'\u00a0'`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.replace` on a `unicode` object but giving `str` arguments to it. The arguments are converted to unicode using the default ASCII encoding, which will fail for bytes not in range(128).

To avoid this problem do not mix `str` and `unicode`. Either pass unicode arguments to unicode methods:

```
new_text = text.decode('utf-8').replace(u'\\u00a0', u' ').replace(u'\\u00ad', u' ')...
```

or do the replacements in the `str` object, assuming `text` is a `str`:

```
new_text = text.replace('\u00a0', ' ').replace('\u00ad', ' ')...
```

Answer (score 0):

The last piece of your chained replaces seems to be the problem.

```
text.replace('0xc3', ' ')
```

THis will try to replace the bytes `0xc3` with a space. In your code snippet it effectively reads

```
text.decode('utf-8').replace('0xc3', ' ')
```

which means that you first decode bytes to a (unicode-)string in python and then want to replace the wrong bytes. It should work if you replace the bytes before decoding:

```
text.replace('0xc3', ' ').decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: is there any way to convert utf-8 encoding directly to text.

Comment: type casting doesn't work also i am working on python 2.7

Comment: @AryanSingh what do yo mean by "utf-8 encoding" and "text"? Those are not types in python.

Comment: The last piece is not the problem.  That replaces the 4-character *text* `0xc3` with a space, which, while not what the OP wants, is still valid code.